# SPO How to Hide column on Display form for specific group permission?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, permissions, column

I want to hide a column for a specific group permission on Display form.

I have found a jQuery code and I have tried to use it but the column still visible to the user that is on this particular group.

I added the code by:settings --> edit the page --> web part --> script editor.

Here is my code:

```
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-663tSdtipgBgyqJXfypOwf9ocmvECGG8Zdl3q+tk+n0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="mysite/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    async: false,
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
       var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;
       var flag = ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Dev Site Add-ins Members']").length != -1);
       if (flag)
  {
         var feedbackField = $("input[title=Comments]");
         feedbackField.parent().parent().parent().hide();       
  }
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is screenshot:

[image: User exist in group]

In this screenshot the comments column still visible for this user:

[image: Comments column still visible]

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: The code you are using can be used to hide the column from new/edit form (observe the jQuery selector here: `$("input[title=Comments]")`). You cannot use the same selector in list view to hide the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

The code you are using can be used to hide the column from new/edit form (observe the jQuery selector here: `$("input[title=Comments]")`). You cannot use the same selector in list view to hide the column.

**Solution**:

Instead of:

```
var feedbackField = $("input[title=Comments]");
feedbackField.parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

**Use this**:

```
//To Hide Column Header
document.querySelector("div[name^='Comments']").parentElement.style.display = "none";

// To Hide all rows for the Comments column
var tdElementsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll("td[class^='ms-vb-lastCell']");
for(var i = 0; i < tdElementsNodeList.length; i++) {
    tdElementsNodeList[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

**Note**:

1. In order to work this code you have to **add comments column as a last column in list view**.
2. This code will break in **Quick Edit** mode. So, better you can disable quick edit mode.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, i have replaced my code with the following: [here](https://pastebin.com/y1jywUzx), i have tried to change the ID of column to the last one which is ID=36 but it doesn't take an effect when i reload the page it get back to ID=12, and i got this console error document.querySelector(...) is null which means that it should be the last column in list view to take effect. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: i have also tried the code on new list,the column hided but on all groups permissions not for a specific group.Also when i removed the code the "Comments" column has been deleted automatically, so it doesn't appear back after reloading the page.

Comment: You need to inspect the elements and find out the correct selectors to use in your code.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, I have inspected the comment elements and i get the following result take a look [here](https://i.imgur.com/khXuqO3.png), so what would be the selector instead of the one you mentioned?

Comment: The query selector for the column header is correct as given in my answer. At which line you are getting the error in console?

Comment: Yes, but the column is being hidden for all groups permission not for the specific group that i mentioned in the code that's the problem now. Anyway [here](https://i.imgur.com/lJd7g3j.png) is my console error.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Sanap, i got a question is it possible to hide more than 1 column because in the code you mentioned you specify that the column we want to hide it and should be last cell, so if we have 2 different columns to hide what will be the code?

Comment: This is something related to element selectors. You just have to find the right selector of the element you want to hide. check this, might help you: [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: If this answer helped you in any way then please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I'll post a new question regarding this thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will advise you to use power apps to hide your fields:

[PowerApps Form - Hiding fields from certain Users](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/PowerApps-Form-Hiding-fields-from-certain-Users/m-p/245685#M72104).